# What version of UI Bootstrap works with Angular 1.6.3?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS v1.6.3 and am trying to find a version of UI.bootstrap that works with it (in terms of Bootstrap's Javascript functionality, such as popover).

This Plunker uses UI.Bootstrap v0.12.0 and the popover works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6ris13k1kZCGLvO7CP4B?p=preview

This Plunker uses UI.Bootstrap v2.5.0 and the popover does not work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NS8OLrKXCfKdHrQ8TRwK?p=preview

This is the popover code that does not work in the latter:

```
<p><a href="#" popover-placement="right" popover="On the Right!">Click me and see popover on the right.</a></p>
```

I suspect I am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer versions of Angular UI Bootstrap, the directive name has been changed from `popover` to `uib-popover`. This is [a fork of your 2nd Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vlgUVEt0jQ8mHkWObMB1?p=preview) in which the popover is displayed on the right of the link.

You can find the new directive name [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should've read the manual more closely.

Comment: @Hoa, i've managed to isolate why my code wasn't working to a particular version of ui-bootstrap, but now I finally understand why it hasn't been running correctly. Thank you. My issue was the same, but with tooltip component